# How can I manage a website with Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I'm starting a new web project, and I'm looking to learn more about Xcode at the same time, so I'm wondering if there's a good way to manage the project through Xcode?

In an ideal world, I would like the  "Run" button to upload the final product files to the web server (or copy them to some local folder that is set to auto-sync using an FTP client) Then I would like it to launch safari (and a number of other test browsers) and have them open the home page.

Additional features that I think are possible:
Have local environment variables that are substituted by some kind of text find/replace action into HTML files as they are copied.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to stay away from XCode for Web development. While it can be done, it really isn't built for it and you will only make things much more difficult than it needs to be. If you really want to learn about XCode then use it for application development, not web development.

There are other IDEs out there specifically for web development that you might like. NetBeans, Coda, Expresso, etc. Personally, I enjoy using Expresso.